# Change submit button colour when form is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want the button to change colour when the form is valid without having to click anything or call a function (like clicking the submit button). As soon as the form is valid the button should change to blue, I can't get my head around this and any help would be much appreciated.

**HTML**:

```
<form id="email_login" method="post">
    <label for="email" class="form_login" id="email_text">Email</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" class="email_login_boxes" id="email_box" >
    <div class="error" id="error_email"></div>

    <label for="password" class="form_login" id="password_text">Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" class="email_login_boxes" id="password_box" >
    <div class="error" id="error_password" ></div>

    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" id="submit_btn" />
</form>
```

**Jquery**:

```
$("input").on("keydown", function (e) {
    return e.which !== 32;
});

$("#error_email").hide();
$("#error_password").hide();

var error_email = false;
var error_password = false;

$("#email_box").click(function(){
    $("#error_email").hide();
});

$("#password_box").click(function(){
    $("#error_password").hide();
});

$("#email_box").focusout(function(){
    check_email();
});

$("#password_box").focusout(function(){
    check_password();
});

function check_email() {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);

    if(pattern.test($("#email_box").val())) {
        $("#error_email").hide();
    } else {
        $("#error_email").html("Invalid email address");
        $("#error_email").show();
        error_email = true;
    }

}

function check_password() {
    var password_length = $("#password_box").val().length;
    if (password_length < 5) {
        $("#error_password").html("Must be greater than 5 characters");
        $("#error_password").show();
        error_password = true;
    } else{
        $("#error_password").hide();
    }
}

$("#email_login").submit(function() {

    error_email = false;
    error_password = false;

    check_email();
    check_password();

    if(error_password == false && error_email == false) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You said "As soon as the form is valid the button should change to blue". This means that the form should be validated after each input event, or when the user mouses out from an input field.

Try this:

```
$("input, textarea").on("keydown keypress keyup paste mouseout", function () {

    var formValid = validationFunction(),
        bgColor   = formValid ? "blue" : "red";

    $("#submit_btn").css("background", bgColor);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$("#email_login input").change(function() {
    // Validating here

    // Change button if validated here
});
```

The change function is called whenever an input is changed within #email_login, so with every change you do your validation. If then the validation is successful, change the button (and probably disable the textfields)